# How to use cocoapods integrated project with OCLint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, oclint

I can build the project and generate OCLint report on a project without cocoapods but when integrated with cocoapods the build for project is successful but the build for **OCLint** results into errors for the file which are present into cocoapods and build fails.

[image]

So how to make build successful for cocoapods with OCLint?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it giving you an error around .plist not being found?

Comment: no. it's giving me error for class used in local pods.

Comment: I am also trying to get OCLint to work with cocoapods, did you get it working?

Comment: @Bob I have posted answer. Please go through it and see if it is working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the script I am using to generate html file for cocoapods integrated project with OCLint.

OCLINT_HOME is the path for oclint downloaded folder. I have renamed the folder to oclintrelease.

```
OCLINT_HOME=/Users/Dheeraj/Downloads/oclintrelease
export PATH=$OCLINT_HOME/bin:$PATH

hash oclint &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo >&2 "oclint not found, analyzing stopped"
exit 1
fi

cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

if [ ! -f compile_commands.json ]; then
echo "[*] compile_commands.json not found, possibly clean was performed"
echo "Workspace Path : ${MY_WORKSPACE}"
echo "[*] starting xcodebuild to rebuild the project.."
# clean previous output

if [ -f xcodebuild.log ]; then
rm xcodebuild.log
echo "Oclint Clean performed"
fi

cd ${SRCROOT}

xcodebuild clean

#build xcodebuild.log
xcodebuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${PROJECT_NAME} -configuration Debug clean build| tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log
#xcodebuild <options>| tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log

echo "[*] transforming xcodebuild.log into compile_commands.json..."
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
#transform it into compile_commands.json
oclint-xcodebuild

fi

echo "[*] starting analyzing"
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

oclint-json-compilation-database -e /Users/Dheeraj/Desktop/sampleCocoaPods/Pods/ -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o /Users/Dheeraj/NewHTMLREPORT.html" | sed 's/\(.*\.\m\{1,2\}:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)/\1 warning:/'
```

It will exclude all the Pods related files.

If you want to include Pods file as well then replace last line in script by :

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o /Users/Dheeraj/NewHTMLREPORT.html" | sed 's/\(.*\.\m\{1,2\}:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)/\1 warning:/'
```

**Notes :**

1. Please try first with a short sample Application including cocoapods and once you have generated report for sample application then integrate script into your real application as building with OCLint takes a lot of time to generate the report.
2. Always clean application and then build with OCLint.

[Link for reference](https://dheerajsingh5792.wordpress.com/2015/05/29/cocoapods-ios-oclint/)